# Cannot resolve method removeAllAppenders [org.apache.logging.log4j]

Tags: java, gradle, log4j2

I used these dependencies
[image]

This function is no longer exists `removeAllAppenders` cannot resolve!

[image: I used apache logger]

What is method instead of this?

Comment: It's not that the function doesn't exist, it's the `log4j` package doesn't.
Did you update the dependency versions from 1.x to 2.18?

You may want to refer to this: [log4j migration](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/migration.html).

Basically some of the package structure changed.

Comment: Please [don't upload text as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13447). Edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. Also see [ask].